# I need help with Wordpress widget title changes

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the wordpress blog widget title such as Archives, Recent Post, Recent Comments.
I search in many ways.  I know it is execute in the file of default-widgets.php. The lines is

```
$title = apply_filters('widget_title',
empty($instance['title']) ? __('Recent
Posts') : $instance['title'],
$instance, $this->id_base);
```

I made the changes in that but it is not reflect anything.  So please help me.

Where and How should be changes this ?

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think hacking around in default-widgets.php is a good idea, unless you really know what you are doing. Changing default-widgets.php means that you have to account for upgrading Wordpress.

Instead, I would suggest creating a new widget to do what you would like it to do and not play around with the Wordpress core.

Here's a decent tutorial on creating this: http://www.lonewolfdesigns.co.uk/create-wordpress-widgets/

Answer (score 0):

I just found this post, and it's exactly what I needed -- I think it might work for you too.  It shows you how to create a filter for the widget_title callback to modify the title however you want to.

http://coderseye.com/2010/modifying-widget-titles-in-wordpress.html

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem too, after reading you tips i have find it out, just edit the 'change here' , problem would be solved.

$title = ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'ｃｈａｎｇｅ　ｈｅｒｅ' );

Answer (score 0):

You can change the title using a filter hook widget_title

```
function new_widget_title($title) {
 if ($title == 'Recent Posts') $title = "Greatest posts";
    return $title;
    }

add_filter ( 'widget_title' , 'new_widget_title', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score -1):

for `WordPress 2.8`

Just open the file named:default-widgets.php which can be located inside the wp-includes directory and delete/modify there and upload to ur server, as simple as that. **This was found before in the widgets.php in previous versions.**Also to remove the `search for` title and replace it u can just delete the text in the php file.This is the line for changing title -

```
 function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract($args);
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? __('Meta') : $instance['title']);
}
```

Keep in mind though that if and when you upgrade to the next version of WP you will also update the `/wp-includes` directory thus overwriting the defaults-widgets.php file, so make a backup copy.

Also look here to **[Disable default WordPress widgets](http://wpbits.wordpress.com/2007/06/15/disable-default-wordpress-widgets/)** like archives,meta-links,recent-posts etc..

Comment: hacking the wordpress core is a bad idea, as noted above.

Answer (score -1):

For adding widgets like archives, recent posts:

1. On dashboard, go to Appearances->Widgets.
2. On left hand side of that window, you will see archives, just move the cursor on it, uou will see a hand symbol on it. Then just drag and place it on right side of that window, below
   the main sidebar. Then, give the title as you want and click save and so on, the same for recent posts.
3. Then, on left top of the blog or website, click your website or blog name to see your archives, recent posts as sidebar.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.